# combining two bar graphs on a single page

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 js to display two bar graphs on the same svg element. Both the graphs have different json data sources. When tested seperately, both the graphs are displayed perfectly.When the entire source code is combined, it doesnt

To append rectangles to the page, I use the following code twice (with changed values in the 'x' and 'y' of .attr)

```
svgd.selectAll("rect")                                  
              .data(dataset_dept_errors)                                        
              .enter()
              .append("rect")
              .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                    return i * 100 + padding_dept;                              // x position of rect as per i->0,1,2,3,...
               })
               .attr("y", function (d) {
                     return (h_dept + yshift_for_dept - yScale(d.NumRuleFailed));                           //y position of rect as per (h-value) to prevent inverted range
               })
               .attr("width", "50")             //depending upon domain->no of inputs - with of band is decided acc. to fit in svg
               .attr("height", function (d) {
                   return yScale(d.NumRuleFailed);                          //depending upon domain->value of inputs - with of band is decided acc. to fit in svg
              })
              .attr("fill", function (d) {                      //colour based on values -> more errors - dark coloured bars
                  return "rgb(" + 100 + "," + 0 + "," + 200 + ")";

              })
                .attr("stroke", "black");
```

I have read that selectAll('rect') will be ignored or it may not work as intended the second time it is encountered, so it should be used only once on one svg. 
How then should I append the next set of rectangles to my page?

EDIT1 : I have the same problem for selectAll('text') for placing multiple text elements on the same page

Comment: take a look to this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/e1192fe405703d8321a5187350910e08

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first append two `g` elements to your `svg` element, position them appropriately, and then create the graphs inside the `g` elements.

Comment: adding an append('g') to all my codes helped me solve my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the root node - `svgd`. Just use two separate root SVG nodes (`svgd`, `svgd2`):

```
var svgd  = d3.select("#svg1"),
    svgd2 = d3.select("#svg2");
```

and then:

```
svgd.selectAll("rect")                                  
    .data(dataset_dept_errors)                                        
    .enter()
    ...

svgd2.selectAll("rect")                                  
     .data(dataset_dept_errors)                                        
     .enter()
     ...
```

and you'll be okay,

Comment: Hi, this assignment of mine has to be done on the same svg only. and apart from this, I have the same problem for selectAll('text') when i have to place multiple text on the same page.

Comment: @SuchitraIyer then please edit your post to clarify that you want to place graphs not on the same page, but into the same SVG element.